# How to upload data from pc to firestore. Getting "Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine."

Tags: kotlin, upload, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to upload a couple of xml files to firestore from my computer (1000 or so). The users in my android app need to be able to search for these files, and because firebase storage doesn't provide that feature I thought I'd just dump them in firestore.

To test it I'm trying to upload 10 files for a start. The code I have looks something like this:

```
fun main(){
    val db = getDatabase()
    getXMLFiles().take(10).forEach { file ->
        db.collection("xml").add(XMLFile(file.name, file))
    }
}

private fun getDatabase() : Firestore {
    val serviceAccount = FileInputStream("<project name>-firebase-adminsdk-<some other stuff>.json")

    val firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
        .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true).build()

    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://<project name>.firebaseio.com")
        .setFirestoreOptions(firestoreOptions)
        .build()

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)

    return FirestoreClient.getFirestore()
}

fun getXMLFiles() = File("/XML").walk().asIterable()

data class XMLFile(val name: String, val file: File)
```

Nothing gets uploaded and half the time (weirdly inconsistently) I get this error message:

```
Apr 15, 2019 2:05:53 PM com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.ConnectException: No route to host (connect failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1075)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1009)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:104)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.runningOnComputeEngine(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:210)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.tryGetComputeCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:290)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentialsUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:207)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:124)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:100)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.defaultCredentials(ServiceOptions.java:304)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:278)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.<init>(FirestoreOptions.java:225)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$Builder.build(FirestoreOptions.java:219)
    at UploaderKt.getDatabase(Uploader.kt:32)
    at UploaderKt.main(Uploader.kt:13)
    at UploaderKt.main(Uploader.kt)

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I checked, and it does find the .json with the credentials, so that is not the problem. I can't find anything anywhere about the error message

```
Apr 15, 2019 2:05:53 PM com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
```

So I hoped someone could help.

Btw, without showing to much, my .json looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "XXX",
  "private_key_id": "XXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----XXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "XXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-XXX%40XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Edit: might be stating the obvious but I have no problems connecting to the internet otherwise